# Generating latex diagram from merise method

Tags: diagrams

I am creating a MCD using Merise2 method. (see on image what a MCD look-like). There are tools that convert MCD into SQLfiles . I would like to know if there is a tool that convert MCD to latex diagram.

I know there are tools to build diagram from scratch (like tikz), and if there is no other way, I can use them.
[image: example of MCD]

edit: I found a website that convert MCD to MLD to LaTeX . (http://mocodo.wingi.net/). It is usefull but I still need to print MCD in LaTeX

Comment: I advise you to insert your example diagram directly into your post.  Many people won't click on an unrecognized link.

Comment: I doubt there is any way to convert it. But even if there was, I'm not sure the conversion is the best way to go about this.

Comment: For non-francophones: MCD = conceptual data model  and MLD = logical data model